# Powershell script not creating a folder using mkdir function

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to create daily folders using a Powershell script, and while the first 2 folders are being created no problem, the third folder on my list isn't being created. Below is my code, and it's the Raw Data folder that's not being created for some reason - any suggestions as to why this may be happening?

```
$months = Get-Date -UFormat %b
$monthl = Get-Date -UFormat %B
$year = Get-Date -UFormat %Y
$timestamp = Get-Date -UFormat "%d%m%Y"
$folderstamp = Get-Date -UFormat "%d-%m-%Y"

mkdir "X:\Client Services & Fulfilment\Fulfilment\CMS\$year\$monthl $year\Investec_AML\$folderstamp"
mkdir "X:\Client Services & Fulfilment\Fulfilment\CMS\$year\$monthl $year\Investec_AML\$folderstamp\Final Output"
mkdir "X:\Client Services & Fulfilment\Fulfilment\CMS\$year\$monthl $year\Investec_AML\$folderstamp\Raw Data"
```

If I write out that line of code on Powershell itself, it returns a LastWriteTime date of 01/01/1601?! See screenshot link below. The mode seems to show all possible modes available?

[powershell screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO6wn.png)

Comment: 1601-01-01 is just the NTFS "zero" time, i.e. the `LastWriteTime` is simply not set. I'm not aware of an option to turn that off explicitly, but the `X:` suggests you're on a mapped drive anyway. It may be an artifact of the network stack. The output suggests the folder *was* created -- follow up with a `dir` to be sure. If it wasn't even created, you're hitting some kind of error (invalid name, name too long?) that isn't getting propagated to the OS for some reason -- again, a not uncommon artifact of network stacks. Try just plain `cmd` and `mkdir`, it should have the same problem.

Comment: I've checked the directory, and the Raw Data folder isn't showing. Using plain cmd and mkdir returns the following: A subdirectory or file X:\Client Services & Fulfilment\Fulfilment\CMS\2019\March 2019\Investec_AML\15-03-2019\Raw Data already exists, but the actual folder isn't showing at all? I don't think the name is too long, or it shouldn't be as the Final Output folder is being created

Comment: It may already exist and not show up in the directory listing as a result of caching. Is this a remote SMB share? You could try disconnecting and reconnecting.

Comment: I'm not sure as to why, but using an underscore instead of a space in the new directory name works fine (Raw_Data)... this will do the trick for me as they are being created to manage data which our team, and our team only, processes. Thanks for your help Jeroen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshot, I can see the `Raw Data` folder indeed exists. Under `Mode` you can see its attributes:

> ```
> d - Directory
> a - Archive
> r - Read-only
> h - Hidden
> s - System
> l - Reparse point, symlink, etc.
> ```

Maybe you should investigate that folder (or link) some more to find out why it is there and if it is a symlink, where it points to.

Anyway, here's your code in more PowerShell style:

```
$now         = Get-Date
$months      = $now.ToString("MMM")
$monthl      = $now.ToString("MMMM")
$year        = $now.Year
$timestamp   = $now.ToString("ddMMyyyy")
$folderstamp = $now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")

$folderName = "X:\Client Services & Fulfilment\Fulfilment\CMS\$year\$monthl $year\Investec_AML\$folderstamp"
try {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $folderName -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path (Join-Path -Path $folderName -ChildPath 'Final Output') -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path (Join-Path -Path $folderName -ChildPath 'Raw Data') -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
}
catch {
    Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: That's my fault I think, I clicked on the tick below and it went from 0 to -1... I thought clicking the tick would have brought it the other way?

Comment: @chillery Ah, tha's ok then. I just don't like (especially downvoters) that do that without giving a reason. If you care to undo it by clicking the triangle upwards that would be great.

Comment: Sorry Theo, I'm getting the following when trying to amend : Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. I'm only on 8 so not sure how to fix this for you

Comment: @chillery Well, nevermind, no big deal. The important thing here is that the code works for you.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever the reason (the word Raw perhaps?), replacing the space in the new directory name with an underscore has worked i.e. 'Raw_Data' instead of 'Raw Data', so I will roll this out for other daily jobs we process that use a similar folder structure.

Thanks to Theo for the tidier code!

```
$now         = Get-Date
$months      = $now.ToString("MMM")
$monthl      = $now.ToString("MMMM")
$year        = $now.Year
$timestamp   = $now.ToString("ddMMyyyy")
$folderstamp = $now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")

$folderName = "X:\Client Services & Fulfilment\Fulfilment\CMS\$year\$monthl $year\Investec_AML\$folderstamp"
try {
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $folderName -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path (Join-Path -Path $folderName -ChildPath 'Final_Output') -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path (Join-Path -Path $folderName -ChildPath 'Raw_Data') -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
}
catch {
Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
}
```